# "Qu'on" et "que l'on" chez Molière

Tags: grammaire, théatre

Bonjour,

Je suis en train de lire [*Le Misanthrope*](http://www.toutmoliere.net/img/pdf/misanthrope.pdf) de Molière.

Je ne comprends pas pourquoi parfois il utilise *qu'on* et parfois *que l'on*.

À titre d'exemple :

> - "Dès **qu'on** voit **qu'on** nous mêle avec tout l'univers" (p. 3).
> - "Il est bon de cacher ce **qu'on** a dans le cœur" (p. 5).
> - "On sait que ce pied plat, digne **qu'on** le confonde" (p. 6).
> - "Et veut **que l'on** soit sage avec sobriété" (p. 6).
> - "Du mérite éclatant **que l'on** découvre en vous" (p. 11).
> - "Et n'allez point quitter, de quoi **que l'on** vous somme" (p. 15).

J'avais appris qu'à l'écrit ce serait toujours préférable d'employer *que l'on*.

Y a-t-il une raison pour l'emploi des deux formes dans ce texte ? Qu'en pensez-vous ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliser deux fois *que l'on* dans une même phrase serait d'un style très lourd:

> *Dès que l'on voit que l'on nous mêle avec tout l'univers.* (!)

Sinon, éviter *qu'on* n'est pas une obligation et c'est ici une variable d'ajustement qui permet à Molière de faire de parfaits [alexandrins](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrin).